# Laser based distance measurement

Tags: pic

Hello everyone,
                         I'm currently involved in a project of measuring distance beyond 50m and upto 100m. Here is my setup, transmitter and receiver at one end and prism(reflector) on the other end. I'm using PIC18F45K22 microcontroller with red laser and BPW34 as photodiode. I tried with CTMU unit in pic with receiver circuit being switched ON using transistor BC547. Readings I got through this is not satisfactory as readings keep on changing depending on intensity of light falling on photodiode. I'm stuck in this one and can't able to move further. Is there any alternative solutions to this or how can I implement this overall ?? And is it possible to use counters in pic ???

Comment: Are you actually trying to implement laser time of flight distance measurement using a PIC and 547 or is that prism your reference?

Comment: Prism is kept at measuring distance to reflect the laser to receiver.

Comment: Can you be more specific. First, provide a schematic of your receiver circuit. Then, tell us what measurement you did, what results you expected, and what you actually observed.

Comment: So you are trying to measure the distance with time of flight?

Comment: Since I need logic 1 and 0 for pic. I have used transistor as a switch with bpw34 output(voltage divider circuit) at base terminal.

Comment: yes, I'm measuring distance with TOF.

Comment: Hate to be the guy to rain on your parade but both the PIC everything else is about 1000 times too slow for that. Your need to be measuring in the multi GHz-range and if you intend to modulate it (as in useful in anything but darkness), your driver needs to be very fast too. s=v*t and v is very high.

Comment: But have you heard of CTMU module in PIC. It measures time even in ns between two edges. That's how I'm measuring time and for this clock is not a big issue as CTMU uses this time to charge the capacitor and measure the voltage.

Comment: What accuracy do you think you will get from a photodiode with 100ns rise time? You will also need to carefully select the laser, it needs to be modulated, should give decent power and should at the same time be eye safe.

Comment: Any other alternatives you think of ?

Comment: Stop and actually *think* about this.  The time for light to go 100 m and back is only 670 ns.  Even for just 1 m accuracy, you need to measure the delay to about 3 ns.

Comment: Any suggestions to take this project forward ?

Comment: Buy a commercial laser distance ranger. If you can afford it, it has a "prism" internally as a reference and is good enough. If it's actual time of flight, you can't afford it for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/269243/how-can-light-be-timed/269254#269254) is an answer that I gave to a similar question someone asked a while back. People are right that using time of flight with a PIC will not work.

Also, this caused confusion last time, but we mean different things by accurate and repeatable in metrology. It is illustrated in the diagram below:
[image: repeatability vs accuracy]
Simply put: repeatable systems produce the same result with multiple measurements. The offset can be calibrated out.

> In general such systems do not use time of flight measurements, at
>   least not directly. Light is just too fast for current systems, if you
>   want better repeatability than a few meters for a cost effective
>   system. There are a few things you can do: geometric measurement,
>   interferometry, modulation.
>
> The simplest thing you can do is to use triangulation. This is how the
>   cheap distance measurement equipment used in construction works. You
>   shine a beam, it reflects, and you pick it up from a different sensor
>   near the receiver. Measure the angle, and you can get a relatively
>   coarse repeatability in the 10's of mm range.
>
> If you need better repeatability, you can use interferometry. You
>   simply measure the difference in phase shift. This can get you to um
>   repeatability. The problem here is that the wavelength changes with
>   atmospheric conditions e.g. 0.1 K rise in temperature generates a 1ppm
>   change. You need to compensate for temperature, pressure, humidity
>   etc. Furthermore, this will give you incremental readings. You need to
>   combine this with the former method.
>
> A relatively new method is to send a modulated waveform. When you
>   receive it back you can use the fact that you know its shape. This
>   then reduces to an optimization problem. A convex optimization problem
>   to be precise. The main disadvantage here is that there is a
>   relationship between bandwidth, and time: the uncertainty principle.
>   But you can get very accurate results.